# Passing checkbox state to PHP

Tags: php, html

```
<input type="hidden" name="check_box_1" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="check_box_1" value="1" />
```

This works fine, however when you click on submit, and the checkbox is ticked, it passes BOTH the hidden value and the original checkbox value to the $_POST variable in php, can this be avoided?

I have the hidden value there, so that unticked checkboxes are passed to the $_POST variable as well as the ticked ones.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use radio buttons instead of checkboxes?

Comment: Used combo-boxes instead, as I needed a way to record the true and false state

Answer (score 2):

The better approach is to remove the hidden field, and simply have a check in PHP:

```
if ($_POST['check_box_1']=='1') { /*Do something for ticked*/ }
else { /*Do something for unticked*/ }
```

Comment: Yeah that will work, but what if you have an array of checkboxes "name =checkbox[]" , the ones that have not been ticked will not be in the $_POST array. Ideally what would be nice is if the unticked checkboxes appeared in the array with a defined value of my choice, that way when it comes to manipulating the data via foreach it would be easy to figure out which checkbox belongs to which.

Comment: as I said below they will all be in the array, as long as you name them something unique. The ones that are unchecked will be in the array as false.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need the hidden field. You should in fact not trust any of the form fields sent in the first place. What this means is that you cannot make code which takes the sent fields and trust them to send the correct data (which I assume you do now).

What you should do is to handle all fields you *expect* to get. That way if you don't get the checkbox value you can still handle that as if it was unticked. Then you also get the added inherent feature of throwing away form data you don't expect in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

No, it will pass all the form data, whatever it is.  The right way to do this is not to set the checkbox via a hidden field but to set the checkbox with whatever its state actually is!

I mean... why are you adding the hidden field to begin with?

Your PHP is receiving two fields named check_box_1, and last time I checked there was no way to guarantee that the params would get read into the REQUEST hash in the exact same order as you sent them, so, there's no way to tell which one will arrive last (that's the one whose value will get set).  So... this is not the right approach to whatever problem you're trying to solve here.

Welcome to Stack, btw! If you find answers useful or helpful, make sure to mark them as correct and vote them up.

Comment: Because when the form is processed, the checkboxes that are not checked are not sent to $_POST variable. Basically, what I am trying to create is a functionality where if the checkbox is already ticked, and the user "unticks" it, then the field in the database is set to false and vice versa (if the other way round)

Comment: checkboxes that are not checked are still sent to the PHP, they just arrive as "false", so maybe you're seeing them as undefined because you're not looking for them the right way?

Comment: When I did $_POST with an array of checkboxes for example name=checkbox[], the only checkboxes that appeared were the ones whose checkboxes had been ticked. The remainder were not in the list.

Comment: yes, because the NAME needs to unique! the type=checkbox you can have as many of those as you want, but the name has to be checkbox1, checkbox2 etc. etc.

Comment: Shouldn't checkbox[] make the name uniqe by presenting the array like this:  [checkbox] => Array
        (
            [0] => True
            [1] => True
            [2] => True
        )
Thanks for the greets. :)

Comment: no no... in your HTML the name has to be unique because the PHP reads it as a hash, so, if you have multiple fields of name "foo" they all get overwritten in the destination hash into the "foo" field, and you end up with just the one that was read last. I think you're thinking of it as arriving like a normal number indexed array, but it's not, it's a string indexed hash.

Comment: Yeah I understand what you are saying; I just used the array as an example in the event that I need to create a list of checkboxes based on x amount of records in the database. X being an unknown amount. So hardcoding the name value, thus making it unique,  would be impossible if I did not do it that way. I would hope that the array index would make each checkbox unique.

Comment: Quick give me the green checkmark before you find something fundamentally wrong with my answer!!!  As to your ambition, unfortunately (or fortunately) the $_POST array IS the hash, so, by the time you're reading it, it's already done whatever indexing it was going to do.

Comment: haha, god, I may have to use a combo box at this rate. Isn't the $POST array populated after the submit button is pressed. I just dont understand why it doesn't pass "false" if the checkbox is not ticked, rather then ommitting it from the list.

Answer (score 0):

That's normal.

They must be both `type="checkbox"` to pass only 1 value.

If you want to get only 1 in any cases you can do:

```
<input type="checkbox" style="display:none;" name="check_box_1" value="0">
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the first input field is of type Checkbox, or else it won't behave like one.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check_box_0" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="check_box_1" value="1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is working normal with your code so far.

I'm assuming you are creating the hidden field so that 0 is passed to the server when the checkbox is not checked. The problem is that they both get passed when the check box *is* checked.

As Death said, the way you *should* be doing it is with a single checkbox and then checking if the value has been sent to the server or not. That's just how checkboxes work.

If you want to have a *default* set then you will have to handle all that on the server side based on weather the checkbox has a value.

For example:

```
$myValue = "";
if(isset($_POST['check_box_1']))
{
    $myValue=$_POST['check_box_1'];
}
else
{
    $myValue="0";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I used a combo box instead, made life so much easier.