# not getting values from my post

Tags: php, html

I have a html form

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">

    <input type="checkbox" name="name[v1]"  />
    <input type="checkbox" name="name[v2]"  />
    <input type="checkbox" name="name[v3]"  />
    <input type="submit" name="update" value="update">
</form>
```

If they is only one check box is ticked then I only see that check box

Array
    (
        [\'v3\'] => on
    )

If I have checked all three box then I see them all.

```
Array
(
    [\'v1\'] => on
    [\'v2\'] => on
    [\'v3\'] => on
)
```

Is they any way I can see all of my checkbox even if they are not checked.

process.php

```
foreach( $_POST['name'] as $k => $v )
{
   echo "key: ".$k;
}
```

Comment: HTML forms never submit unchecked checkboxes.

Comment: @sebas: what javascript? `name[v1]` is a perfectly acceptable value for an HTML name attribute.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing checkbox state to PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768024/passing-checkbox-state-to-php)

Comment: Is they any way I can submit them, ask i need to change values in db.

Comment: You can't get the value of an unchecked checkbox. You can just loop through the possible values, and see which entries exist in $_POST. The alternative would be to use a radio or submit input type.

Comment: you shouldn't need to rely on the form fields, in fact its a bad idea, some one could add some, before posting, you still need to validate server side no matter what.

Comment: Try print_r($_POST); to see what data is being sent, it's a time saver!

Comment: And make sure form method is post, easy enough mistake

Comment: @Lalajee: why do you need to retrieve values of unchecked checkboxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkboxes and radio buttons are not passed on to the processing script if they don't have a "checked" attribute set. This is HTML4 by design.

The only way you can set a state is using something like:

```
if(!isset($_POST['mycheckbox'])){ $_POST['mycheckbox'] = 0; }
```

or better yet:

```
$_POST['mycheckbox'] = isset($_POST['checkbox']);
```

Regarding radio buttons, you should only use the first version since radio buttons can have more than one value so instead of setting a TRUE/FALSE in them, you want to set a default value instead.

Another note, DISABLED elements are not posted, even if they have a value, you will never see them, this is another design feature of HTML4+